# Progress Dialog in android does not dismiss

Tags: android

Sorry If I am repeating question,

I am using following code in Handler class :-

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(SensorDetailActivity.this);
progressDialog.show();
if (msg.what == Commands.COMMAND_READ.getIndex()) {
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf);
                final EditText currentSensorMeasurement = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.currentSensorMeaurmentEdit);
                currentSensorMeasurement.setText(readMessage.substring(readMessage.indexOf(" ") + 1,readMessage.indexOf(';')));
                if (currentSensorMeasurement.getText().toString().indexOf(';') > -1) {
                    currentSensorMeasurement.setText(currentSensorMeasurement.getText().toString().replace(';', ' ').trim());
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                 }
```

I am showing progress dialog, and after completing the operation i am dismissing the progress dialog.But it doesn't dismiss.

Comment: Debug your code make sure the statement ` progressDialog.dismiss();` is executing .

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Second thing confirm that you are not creating multiple instances of Progress dialog

Comment: yes it is executing

Comment: I am sending message to handler from thread, so yes the multiple instances are created Naved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your condition meets to dismiss the progress  dialog? Becuase i don't see a else part.As per your code if your condition do no meet then in that case your progress dialog will not dismiss.

```
if (currentSensorMeasurement.getText().toString().indexOf(';') > -1) {
                    currentSensorMeasurement.setText(currentSensorMeasurement.getText().toString().replace(';', ' ').trim());
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                 }
```